# expel object from isolation mode

Tags: shortcut

I recently switch to Blender 3.2

I quite often go into isolation mode. When I done with some part I wanna expel (don't know how to call in properly, sorry) an object I no longer working on from isolation mode. It was previously done by hitting "m", but now this key is universally for switching collections. I asked google what is the new keyboard shortcut, but it don't understand what I looking for.

When I tired of googling I "overcoming" the problem by selecting "a" to select all. Deselect by hand objects I don't want in my isolation mode. Then "/" to end isolation mode and then hitting "/" again to isolate only objects I need. The problem is the file is big The whole procedure takes approximately 5 minutes, because loading all the objects. I getting tired of it.

Can someone tell me what is the new shortcut?

(Sorry for bad English)

Comment: I think you're looking for menu entry *View > Local View > Remove From Local View* with shortcut *Alt+Numpad /*

Comment: I've always just hit forward slash "/" on the numpad to toggle between the two states. This just works on the object which has been selected in Object mode of course.

Comment: THX! @Blunder it is what I was looking for.